# Android shared element transition does not work

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have 2 **Activities** each having an ImageView.First one has an image which upon clicked should do the transition magic while moving to the next activity.It goes to the next activity,but for some strange reason transition is not working.

Activity1 Screenshot:

[image]

Activity2 Screenshot

[image]

Activity1.java:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                {
                    Intent intent =new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                    ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions=ActivityOptionsCompat.
                            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity1.this,imageView,"shift");

                    ActivityCompat.startActivity(Activity1.this,intent,activityOptions.toBundle());
                }
```

activity1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/th"
    android:transitionName="shift"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:transitionName="shift"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where you are setting image in ImageView of activity2.xml ?

Comment: Wont it automatically set itself to the imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not setting image for ImageView in your actvity2.xml**

Add this in your ImageView of actvity2.xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/th"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use element transition you must add `windowActivityTransitions` attribute to your app Theme.

```
  <!-- enable window content transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```

Also look at official Android doc:   [Start an activity using an animation](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity#custom-trans) .

Comment: i added windowContentTransition

Comment: But still adding "android:windowActivityTransitions">true didnot work